# Regex for picking up a color name from HTTP response

Tags: c, regex, performance-testing, loadrunner

I am using Loadrunner and need to come up with a regex that will pick up a particular word from the HTTP response coming in and save it in a parameter.

The response looks like this:

```
\t\t\t\t\t<option value="Rose taupe" id="WD26" class="WD26">Rose taupe</option>\n
\t\t\t\t\t<option value="Myrtle" id="WD20" class="WD20">Myrtle</option>\n
\t\t\t\t\t<option value="Deep carmine pink" id="WD142" class="WD142">Deep carmine pink</option>\n
\t\t\t\t\t<option value="Wild Strawberry" id="WD66" class="WD66">Wild Strawberry</option>\n
\t\t\t\t\t<option value="Cream" id="WD72" selected="selected" class="WD72">Cream</option>\n
\t\t\t\t\t<option value="Tangerine yellow" id="WD94" class="WD94">Tangerine yellow</option>\n
```

I want to pick up the color that is selected in a drop down menu in the front end, in the response this color line has selected="selected" in it. This is however random for each instance hence the regex has to pickup the color name from the line which contains selected="selected".

I then have to use it in my script as follows:

```
web_reg_save_param_regexp ("ParamName=SelectedColor",
"RegExp=-regular expression here-",
"Ordinal=All",
LAST);
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: I would think an HTML parser would be far more suited to this task than a RegEx.

Comment: Thank you, but I'm unsure if you can use that in LR.

Comment: This is one possible alternative: `<option value="([^"]*)" id="[^"]*" selected="selected"`    It works for your example but keep in mind if the HTML attributes change order this won't work.  If you have to handle the attributes changing order then regex probably isn't the answer.

Comment: Thanks for that Jerry, the attributes don't really change order so I will try your solution now. Cheers!

Comment: Seems to be your doing "My Load Test Correlation Challenge " created by Stuart Moncrieff. From the website: "Please don’t share your solutions, ask for help, or help others. This is meant to be a challenge."

So you appear to be violating one of the primary rules in this website. I have looked at this challenge and it's really good to increase someone's knowledge.

Comment: Well yeah, I wouldn't deny that. I'm a beginner who's started using LR a month ago and never really used code, have been trying this for 2 weeks and finally asked. I'm doing the rest of it by myself, this is the only place where I really got stuck and gave in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The RegExp `/<\s*option\s+(?=.*selected\s*=).*value\s*=\s*(?:"([^"]*)"|'([^']*)')/g` will match the `option` tag with the `selected` attribute. The order of attributes is arbitrary. If attribute quotes may be `'` then you need to handle the second match group, see example.

```js
var s = '\t\t\t\t\t<option value="Rose taupe" id="WD26" class="WD26">Rose taupe</option>\n' +
        '\t\t\t\t\t<option value="Myrtle" id="WD20" class="WD20">Myrtle</option>\n' +
        '\t\t\t\t\t<option value="Deep carmine pink" id="WD142" class="WD142">Deep carmine pink</option>\n' +
        '\t\t\t\t\t<option value="Wild Strawberry" id="WD66" class="WD66">Wild Strawberry</option>\n' +

        '\t\t\t\t\t<option value="Cream" id="WD72" selected="selected" class="WD72">Cream</option>\n' +

        '\t\t\t\t\t<option id="WD72" value=\'Cream\' selected="selected" class="WD72">Cream</option>\n' +

        '\t\t\t\t\t<option value="Tangerine yellow" id="WD94" class="WD94">Tangerine yellow</option>\n';

var re = /<\s*option\s+(?=.*selected\s*=).*value\s*=\s*(?:"([^"]*)"|'([^']*)')/g;
var m;

while (m = re.exec(s)) {
    console.log("Selected color: " + (m[1]||m[2]) + ", match " + m[0]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Below code will work.

```
web_reg_save_param_ex(
        "ParamName=SelectedItem",
        "LB/IC/DIG=id=\"^^^^\" selected=\"selected\"",
        "RB=</option>",
        "Ordinal=1",
        SEARCH_FILTERS,
        "Scope=ALL",
        LAST);
```